# SSIS Concatenate Time Stamp Columns and Integer

Tags: ssis

I have these 3 columns in SSIS, my dates are in DT_DBTIMESTAMP and my Company ID in INT:

```
BeginDate                EndDate                       CompanyId
2019-01-01 00:00:00.000  2019-06-01 00:00:00.000           5
```

I want has result this in the column Concat:

```
BeginDate                    EndDate                     CompanyId         Concat    
2019-01-01 00:00:00.000  2019-06-01 00:00:00.000           5              2001-01-01;2019-06-01;5
```

How i can acheive this result?

Comment: I am not sure if this is an example of many more columns, but you may want to consider a hash function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may nee to convert them to string and concatenate them in a Derived Column transformation with a expression like this:

```
(DT_WSTR,30)(BeginDate) + ";" + (DT_WSTR,30)(EndDate) + ";" + (DT_WSTR,30)(CompanyId)
```